# I changed target .net version and it caused a bunch of data set errors how do i fix it?

Tags: c#, .net

as the title states i changed the target .net framework from version 4.0 to version 4.6.1 well now my project will not compile.. even after changing the target back to 4.0 it still will not compile!

here are the errors im getting

main form shows

Failed to parse method 'InitializeComponent'. The parser reported the following error 'Invalid symbol kind: Namespace'. Please look in the Task List for potential errors.

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.OnMethodPopulateStatements(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.CodeDom.CodeMemberMethod.get_Statements()
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)

build errors shows

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'TrackingNumbersDataSet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'TrackingNumbersDataSetTableAdapters' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'TrackingNumbersDataSetTableAdapters' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error       Custom tool error: Failed to generate code. Failed to generate code. Exception of type 'System.Data.Design.InternalException' was thrown. Exception of type 'System.Data.Design.InternalException' was thrown.

any ideas on how i can get it to compile?

Comment: deleted all code related to TrackingNumbersDataSet & TrackingNumbersDataSetTableAdapters and was able to get it to build so apparently the new .net framework doesn't like them!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you have accidentally entered `Namespace` instead of `namespace`. This is the error you are seeing in the error list. Correct that and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check, is there any other project referenced by your error project which .net target lower than your current project.

example :

1. BaseProject (target .net is 3.5 or 4.0)
2. ComponentProject (before error shown up, you're using .net 4.0)
   referenced by BaseProject and you changed it into 4.6.1

When you turn back into .net 4.0, please make sure to rebuild the ComponentProject

Please be careful to change target of .net framework, and make sure the .net framework of **referenced** project not higher than any other project that references that project.

Comment: deleted all code related to TrackingNumbersDataSet & TrackingNumbersDataSetTableAdapters and was able to get it to build so apparently the new .net framework doesn't like them!